# ActionEvent of a component on a table cell doesn't take place

Tags: java, swing, lwuit, tablemodel, actionevent

My code belongs to LWUIT apps but  problem about something common between LWUIT and java swing.

I have a table there is a Button set  on the last cell of it  as a component

My question simply  why is there no action takes place when I press   that button.

I tried checkbox also but I even couldn't  do check.

```
Button b,b2;

Object  [][] elhind;

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

 {
 elhind  = new  String[1][9];
 String elhind  [][] = {{"Netherlands","Germany","Austria","Romania","Bulgaria","England","Walse","Ireland","Belgium"}};

 Object ob  [][] = new  String[elhind.length][10];

 for(int col=0;col<9;col++) 
{

 for(int j=0;j<elhind.length;j++)
 {

  ob[j][col] = elhind[j][col];

 }
  }
  TableModel  model = new DefaultTableModel( new String[]{"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11"ob)   {
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
 {
 return true;  
 }
 };

 elhind  = new  String[1][10];
 ob = new  String[1][10];

 Table  table = new Table(model,true);

 for(int col=0;col<10;col++)
 for(int j=0;j<1;j++)

 try
 {

 if(col ==8)
 {
  Button cb =new Button("lam");
 cb.setFocus(true);
 cb.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
 {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent acv)
{

System.out.print("Action done");
}
 });

 table.addComponent(cb);

}
 else 
 {
  model.setValueAt(j, col, elhind[j++][col++] )   ;
 }
 }
catch(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ee)
{
}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException e3)
{
}
 }

}

);
```

Overriding createCell method on table class doesn't solve the problem

```
Table  table = new Table(model,true)
{     
protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row,
final int column, boolean editable) {
if (column == 0) {
try {
Button cod = new Button("cod");
cod.getStyle().setBgColor(0x00f0f0);
cod.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEventacv)                          
{      
System.out.print("hello LWuit");
} 
});
return cod;
}  
catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
 }
 return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
 }
 } ;
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: You need to use custom `CellEditor` with `JButton`, take a look at [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Comment: please can you explain this code for me , getActionCommand() couldn't be used  in LWUIT app      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );
        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
    }

Comment: Renderer is responsible for painting in the JTables view, don't put JComponent to the XxxTableModel, there is stored only value, description, for rendered component, many times Q&A here, incl. hover_over effect, basically everything is described in oracle tutorial - how to use tables

Comment: @mKorbel Are you mean My Idea is totally wrong?

Comment: yes, but nothing futher, cleaver without an SSCCE

Comment: @mkorbel See this code works normally  http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/

Comment: yes true very good code, quite refference code

Comment: Anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add buttons to a Table and you shouldn't invoke `setFocus()`.

Either add the button as a separate component to a common parent or override the tables createCell method to generate a button for that case (the former it easier).

Use requestFocus() instead of setFocus().

Comment: Overriding createCell method on table class didn't solve the problem!   plz see my thread again

Comment: How is it not working? Did you reach that code? 
That should work but you should also check the row since this method is also invoked for the header cell.

Comment: I am sorry it works perfectly, I didn't notice well.