# java pass data to JTable's row upon button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm doing a java app which has to pass an initialized array of string to display as a row to a JTable.

This is what I tried:

```
      Object[] _row1;

      public PrintMeNow() {
            table = new JTable();
    table.setBounds(16, 203, 362, 16);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
                _row1, {2,2,2}, {3,3,3}, {4,4,4}
        },
        new String[] {
            "QTY", "Item Code", "Amount"
        }
    ));

     }

  btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           _row1 = new Object[]{"DN Korina", "DN Madrid", "DN Romania"};
      }
  });
```

But when I pressed the start button, it's not filling the row. What am I doing wrong in here? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: May the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514181/actionevent-of-a-component-on-a-table-cell-doesnt-take-place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is add a row to the `Model`. Something like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"DN Korina", "DN Madrid", "DN Romania"});
}
```

The easiest way is to set up you model before hand to have no rows

```
String[] colNames = {
       "QTY", "Item Code", "Amount"
};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);  <== 0 rows
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then whatever rows you want to add, just add to the model

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"DN Korina", "DN Madrid", "DN Romania"});
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    private String[] colNames = { "Col 1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private MyStack myStack = new MyStack();
    private Stack<Integer[]> stack;

    private JButton button = new JButton("Add Row");

    public TestTable() {
        stack = myStack.getStack();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    Integer[] array = stack.pop();
                    model.addRow(array);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestTable();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyStack {
    public Stack<Integer[]> stack = new Stack<Integer[]>();

    public MyStack() {
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Integer[] array = new Integer[5];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                array[j] = i * k * (j + 1);
            }
            k++;
            stack.push(array);
        }
    }

    public Stack<Integer[]> getStack() {
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Explanation

- I have a MyStack class that has a `Stack`. It could be any data structure like an array even, but I chose to use a `Stack` because I can just `.pop()` it. And the get the `Integer[]`.
- I instantiate that class in the GUI class
- I then extract that `Stack`. Keep in mind the `Stack` holds `Integer[]`'s
- As i explained, you want to add a single dimension array to the `model`.
- So every time I click the button, an `Integer[]` is pulled out of the `Stack`, then I just add that array to the `model` as a row.

Comment: Hello thanks for this example, but what if I don't know what rows are to pass? Meaning I have another class, from their I have to pass array of string to this class?

Comment: It However you get that data, just `model.addRow(a single Dim array)`

Comment: Create an instance of that class in the GUI class and extract the data from it

Comment: Can you give me some sample implementations of that?

Comment: See my **UPDATE** when you run it, just click the Button

Comment: By the way can you explain those lines of codes to me? thanks

Comment: Which lines? See my explanation at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

> But when I pressed the start button, it's not filling the row. What am
>   I doing wrong in here?

- your code inside `ActionListener` missing any code to `addRow` to `JTable`  or to `DefaultTableModel` (`table.getModel....`)
- in the case that you are using `DefaultTableModel` doesn't matter if is row added to `JTable` or `DefaultTableModel`
- don't to use `NullLayout` in Swing, Swing is designated to be laid by using `LayoutManager`

Comment: How do you know that I'm using NullLayout?

Comment: Because for the sake of my example I use AbsoluteLayout